# liquibase - 1 change sets had duplicate identifiers

Tags: liquibase

Liquibase tells me :

```
1 change sets had duplicate identifiers
          classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/20160610094343_changelog.xml::1465551835616-1::techvalley (generated)
```

I have looked for id **1465551835616-1** in the code of my app, it's only in the file 20160610094343_changelog.xml (and only once).  I don't understand where this error can come from.

Comment: That will be hard to answer without looking into your files/code. I can only think of two reasons: You missed something when you were looking for the id. Or liquibase is also including already ran changesets from the databasechangelog table into the compare and maybe that changeset has already been in the databasechangelog table (but that is just a wild guess). It will compare the changesets  just by `id` and `author` (without the md5 checksum). So maybe you can verify again, that all of your changesets have a different `id` and `author`.

Comment: This can occur if the same changelog file is included twice in your master.xml

Answer (score 22):

This can occur if the same changelog file is included twice in your `master.xml` file

Answer (score 6):

Be careful in the ids from the change sets, I had two duplicate ids and that was the problem

Answer (score 3):

When including files Liquibase does not check if you included a file twice. It is master.xml is not idiot-proof with respect to including files.

Make sure your **changelog-master.xml** file is correct, as **you most likely have duplicates in it**.

Answer (score 0):

The file 20160610094343_changelog.xml is included in a changelog master file; please review that changelog master file, the filename in question might be in there at least twice, remove the duplicates and then continue on.

I know it's an old question; I just happen to have faced the same situation a couple of days ago. and it usually happens when you generate the change file more than once and decide to overwrites; in the master changelog file the filename is always added even if you decided to overwrite.