# how do i create same tables in different schemas using liquibase

Tags: liquibase

Imagine i had a table 'some-table' that i want to create in multiple schemas. File called 'create-some-table.yaml'

```
 databaseChangeLog:
      - changeSet:
          id: create-some-table
          runOnChange: true
          author: gimazov (generated)
          preConditions:
            - onFail: MARK_RAN
              not:
                tableExists:
                  tableName: some-table
          changes:
            - createTable:
                columns:
                  - column:
                      autoIncrement: true
                      constraints:
                        nullable: false
                        primaryKey: true
                        primaryKeyName: some-table_pkey
                      name: id
                      type: BIGINT
                tableName: some-table
                schemaName: ${schema}
```

Then there's a yaml file 'schema1.yaml' that includes the previous file and sets schema

```
 databaseChangeLog:
  - property:
      name: schema
      value: schema1
  - include:
      file: classpath:/db/changelog/create-some-table.yaml
```

Then the same file as the above one just named 'schema2.yaml' with corresponding schema name

The last thing is changelog-master which is pretty simple

```
databaseChangeLog:
    - include:
        file: classpath:/db/changelog/schema1.yaml
    - include:
        file: classpath:/db/changelog/schema2.yaml
```

Is there any way i can do something similar to this, thanks :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set up liquibase in Spring for multiple data sources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43523971/how-to-set-up-liquibase-in-spring-for-multiple-data-sources)

Comment: No, i don't think so :(

Answer (score 0):

what about having this structure?

```
master.changelog.yaml
  schemas
    schema1.changelog.yaml
    schema2.changelog.yaml
  templates
    templates.changelog.yaml
    table1.template.yaml
    table2.template.yaml
    ...
```

so in `master.changelog.yaml` you will include `schema1.changelog.yaml` and `schema2.changelog.yaml`. In both of them you will include `templates.changelog.yaml` and set the parameters for schema. Then in `templates.changelog.yaml` you will include all templates that are common for all schemas. I think that should work however I have no experiences with `yaml` format in `liquibase`. For xml that shouldn't be issue.

Comment: How can you avoid the problem of including the same file multiple times? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52210833/13574635